# Draw NSString on to a PDF page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

In my application, I'm creating a PDF. I'm able to draw **single line string**. But I want to draw a **string with multiple lines**. Here's my code

```
NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filename = @"test.pdf";
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:documentsDirectory, filename, nil]];

// Create PDF context
CGContextRef pdfContext = CGPDFContextCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)fileURL, NULL, NULL);
CGPDFContextBeginPage(pdfContext, NULL);
UIGraphicsPushContext(pdfContext);

// Flip coordinate system
CGRect bounds = CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(pdfContext);
CGContextScaleCTM(pdfContext, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextTranslateCTM(pdfContext, 0.0, -bounds.size.height);

// String to show
NSString *strTest=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@\n%@", @"one",@"two"];
NSLog(@"%@", strTest);
// Drawing commands

[strTest drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(100, 100) withFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:12.0f]];

// Clean up
UIGraphicsPopContext();
CGPDFContextEndPage(pdfContext);
CGPDFContextClose(pdfContext);
```

This is creating a PDF with sigle lined string.

```
One Two
```

But I want to draw the string as it is (two line string)

```
One
Two
```

How can I modify this code to draw a string with multiple lines?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [`drawInRect:withFont:` method](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/drawInRect%3awithFont%3a), or one of the other `drawInRect:...` methods.